# text field is not getting clear

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I have a textfield from which I show a popover for textfield value string.

When I edit the text field the clear button is visible, however, when I click the clear button, 
textfield text doesn't disappear but the popover is dismissed.

How can I fix this please?

Below is code fragment

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([popOverController isPopoverVisible]) 
    {
        [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    }

    if(textField.tag == SERVER_TAG){

        if ([[self getServerList] count]) {
            [self createPopUp];
        }
    } else {
        [serverNameTf resignFirstResponder];
    }

}




- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you paste your code that you tried.

But as i understood from your question, you may not set the TEXTFIELDs delegate,

so st the textfields delegate to self.

**ie. textfield.delegate = self**

and also make changes as >>

[textField setText:@""];

[popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

Try this out.

Comment: I have set delegate for textfield, as its working for other text fields. Its not working for the textfield from which popover is visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([popOverController isPopoverVisible]) 
{
    [textField setText:@""];
    [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: I think your solution will clear text when textfield is selected.
But my requirement is to clear textfield using clear button.